# Why are link properties not working in this code example?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I'm trying to style my links but when I apply the style it changes nothing.

```css
.navlinks {
  a:link {
    color: #e5e5e5;
  }
  a:visited {
    color: #1f4e8c;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="site-navigator">
  <a href="index.html" class="navlinks">Startseite</a>
  <a href="Leistungen.html" class="navlinks">Leistungen</a>
  <a href="Kontakt.html" class="navlinks">Kontakt</a>
  <a href="Impressum.html" class="navlinks">Impressum</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Its `a.navlinks{color: #e5e5e5;}` not `.navlinks a:link {color: #e5e5e5;}`

Comment: @Simplicius yes, that's what I said: It's *not* .navlinks a:link {color: #e5e5e5;} (which is what they have in their code).

Answer (score 1):

Please try this,

Your css code  error

```
.navlinks{
  a:link {color: #e5e5e5;}
  a:visited{color:#1f4e8c;}
}
```

changes to **CSS**

```
a.navlinks:link {color: #00cc00;}
a.navlinks:visited{color:#111;}
```

changes to **SCSS**

```
a{
    &.navlinks{
        &:link{color: #00cc00;}
        &:visited{color:#111;}
    }
}
```

```css
a.navlinks:link {color: #00cc00;}
a.navlinks:visited{color:#111;}
```

```html
 <div id="site-navigator">
    <a href="index.html" class="navlinks">Startseite</a>
    <a href="Leistungen.html" class="navlinks">Leistungen</a>
    <a href="Kontakt.html" class="navlinks">Kontakt</a>
    <a href="Impressum.html" class="navlinks">Impressum</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Be careful asking people to accept your answer! You can let them know how to accept an answer, but you can't *ask* them to accept.

Comment: @RubixOverflow. Answers *can't* be accepted earlier then 15 mins from when the post was originally made, also please don't beg for it just to get reputation.

Answer (score 1):

**Change your css to this.**

```css
a.navlinks {
  &:link {
    color: #e5e5e5;
  }
  &:visited {
    color: #1f4e8c;
  }
}
```

**Here's a little cheat sheet for future reference**

`" "`(space) = **subelements**

`&` and `""`(no space) = **current element**  `//here a.navlinks = <a class="navlinks">`

`>` = **inner adjacent/immediate element**

So, above code denotes this

```
<a class="navlinks" :link>
<a class="navlinks" :visited>
```

```css
/* beacause plain css will not support above format */

a.navlinks:link { color: red; }

a.navlinks:visited { color: orange; }
```

```html
<div id="site-navigator">
  <a href="index.html" class="navlinks">Startseite</a>
  <a href="Leistungen.html" class="navlinks">Leistungen</a>
  <a href="Kontakt.html" class="navlinks">Kontakt</a>
  <a href="Impressum.html" class="navlinks">Impressum</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go ;)

```
a {
  &.navlinks {
    &:link {
      color: #e5e5e5;
    }
    
    &:visited {
      color: #1f4e8c;
    }
    
    &:hover {
      //
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a selection error in your CSS code.

```
.navlinks a:link {
  color: #e5e5e5;
}
.navlinks a:visited {
  color: #1f4e8c;
}
```